# Install JRebel on Rational SW Architect (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, rational-rsa

I am trying to install the class reloading utility JRebel (http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) on a java web project we are working on. The demo in the site's video seems very promising, however we have not been able to install it.

We are using IBM Rational Software Architect v7.0.0. Following the installation instructions we go to "Help" > "Software Updates" > "Find and Install" and add the new update site. Then we get the JRebel plugins selection window, and upon selecting we get the following error message:

`Requested operation cannot be performed because it would invalidate the current configuration. See details for more information.
  JRebel Eclipse Debugger Integration (Optional) (1.2.0.201008061519) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.debug.ui (3.3.0)", or later version.
  JRebel Eclipse Integration (1.2.0.201008061519) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.debug.ui (3.3.0)", or later version.
  JRebel RAD Integration (Optional) (1.2.0.201008061519) requires plug-in "org.eclipse.debug.ui (3.3.0)", or later version.`

I looked under the "C:\Program Files\IBM\SDPShared\plugins" location and found what seems to be newer versions of the required plugin:

`org.eclipse.debug.ui_3.4.2.v20090110_r342.jar
org.eclipse.debug.core_3.4.1.v20090106_r342.jar`

Not sure if this is sufficient as to having the required plugins installed. We unzipped the jars at the same location and restarted the IDE and did not work. Also, we looked into the "Find and Install" option for these plugins but no success so far.

Could you please provide advice on the correct installation for these plugins, surely we are missing something. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: JRebel is a commercial product. Wouldn't it be simpler just to use their tech support channels? http://www.zeroturnaround.com/forum/

Comment: Actually I don't mean been JRebel the problem itself. I see the problem being more of the org.eclipse.debug.*.jar drivers installation that seem to be not working, hence my question.

I posted the question on their site too, waiting for an answer. Just wanted to save some time since this is urgent. I will keep you updated though. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I work for ZeroTurnaround

If I rememember correctly, isn't RSA 7.0 based on the same version of Eclipse as RAD 7.0 (Eclipse 3.2)?

We only have a Debugger plug-in for RAD/RSA 7.0 (under separate category in update site).

For our main plug-in Eclipse 3.3 or later (RAD/RSA 7.5 or later) is required.

I think it is possible that your SDPShared folder contains plug-ins from some newer IBM tools that are not actually active in RSA 7.0. You could check in Help -> About -> Plug-in Details (or the equivalent in that RSA version, which I don't have at hand) and see the exact version of org.eclipse.debug.ui plug-in that it uses.